# Merge several files on the basis of the md5sum

Tags: files, scripting, hashsum

I have a file data.txt, which was divided into fragments. I need to properly combine fragments of files so that the original file was created data.txt. I do not know what procedure does this, because the names of fragments do not have a hierarchy. But I have an `md5sum` file data.txt (which lists the fragments). How can I use the `md5sum` file to restore the entire file from its fragments?

Comment: If you could deduce the hash of the global file by some easy operation on the hash of the parts, MD5 would be easy to parallelize. But MD5 is not parallelizable at all. You'll need to test the combinations or infer the correct order from the contents.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -MAlgorithm::Combinatorics=permutations \
  -le '$i=permutations(\@ARGV); while ($p=$i->next) { $n++; print "combo$n @$p" }' frag1 frag2 frag3 frag4 \
| while read out a b c d; do cat $a $b $c $d > $out; md5 $out; done
```

Or `md5sum` instead of `md5` if you have the GNU tools.

Answer (score 0):

How many fragments are there? It sounds like you would have to try every permutation of the fragments (or until you hit the right one), therefore even solving the problem for a relatively small amount of fragments will result in a large amount of work.

Comment: There is a 4 fragments of file data.txt. I can not based on checksum merge file?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the checksum of a part doesn't help calculate the checksum of the whole, so you'll have to calculate the checksum of all possible permutations until you find the right one. If you have *n* parts, there are *n*! (factorial of *n*) permutations, and if they're all equally likely you'll have to process *n*!/2 on average until you find the right one.

When you need to calculate the checksum of multiple strings with the same prefix, you can save time by storing the internal state of the MD5 function. For example, with three parts (X, Y, Z), you'd need to calculate MD5(X+Y+Z), MD5(X+Z+Y), MD5(Y+X+Z), MD5(Y+Z+X), MD5(Z+X+Y) and MD5(Z+Y+X). If you start the calculation of MD5(X,…) then duplicate the state and finish the calculation for both suffixes Y+Z and Z+Y. But you need the internal state for that, not the output, and most tools don't give access to the internal state.

Python's [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) provides a `copy` method to copy a hash function's internal state. It also has an [iterator to enumerate permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) in its standard library.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import hashlib, itertools, sys

def look_for_permutation(goal, filenames):
    n = len(filenames)
    files = map(open, filenames)
    previous = map(lambda _: None, filenames)
    states = [hashlib.md5()] + [None] * (n-2)
    for current in itertools.permutations(files):
        i = 0
        while current[i] == previous[i]:
            i += 1
        state = states[i].copy()
        for f in current[i:n-2]:
            state.update(f.read())
            i += 1
            states[i] = state.copy()
            f.seek(0)
        state.update(current[n-2].read())
        current[n-2].seek(0)
        state.update(current[n-1].read())
        if state.hexdigest() == goal:
            return current
        current[n-1].seek(0)
        previous = current
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = look_for_permutation(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2:])
    if result:
        for f in result: print f.name
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        sys.exit(1)
```

This script optimizes the hash calculations but reads the file contents repeatedly. If the files contents fit in memory, you can make it a little faster by loading the files once and for all.